# mysql check manual error

Tags: php, mysql

Came across an error i have never seen before after writing the following code:

```
$query= "UPDATE `Pharm_Log` SET `text` = ". $bloodtest . " WHERE `id` = " . $patientid;
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

My error message was this

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Pressure Test: 235/43 WHERE `id` = 1' at line 1"

Any one have any idea on how to fix this? would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are probably also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from. Don't build SQL queries by mashing strings together.

Comment: You have some PHP that generates some SQL. You have a problem with the SQL. The PHP is incomplete so we can't run it to see what the final value of `$query` is. Don't you think it would easier to debug the SQL if we could see the SQL?

Answer (score 8):

the string literal (*value of `$bloodtest`*) must be wrap with single quotes,

```
$query= "UPDATE `Pharm_Log` SET `text` = '". $bloodtest . "' WHERE `id` = " . $patientid;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply i was asking that myself however, when it is wrapped in single quotes i get a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error which is something to do with the quotes no?

Comment: how about `"UPDATE Pharm_Log SET text = '$bloodtest' WHERE id = $patientid";` ?